# An infinity and $2$-norm inequality on a finite dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have a space of interpolants given by:
\begin{equation}
 S:= \left\{ \sum_{i \in F} c_i \eta\Bigl(\frac{t-ih}{h\sqrt{D}}\Bigr):(c_i)_{i \in F} \subset \mathbb{R} \right\}.
\end{equation}
where $F$ is a finite set, $h>0, D>0$. I know $S \subset L^2([0,1];\mathbb{R})$. Let $T \subset S$, which is also a finite dimensional subspace of $L^2$. Let $f,g \in T$. I know the following estimate
$$\| f-g \|_2 \le \varepsilon_0$$
I want to find the estimate $\|f-g\|_{\infty}.$ To that end, I want to know that is there any way, or any known inequality, such that I can bound $\|f-g\|_{\infty}$ by $\|f-g\|_{2}$? I can not directly use the fact that norms are comparable in finite dimensions because $f,g$ are functions.

One particular way I was thinking of is using Reproducing kernel Hilbert space methods. As $T$ is a finite dim subspace of $L^2$ it is an RKHS; thus
$$|f(x)-g(x)|\le \sqrt{K}\|f-g\|_{H}$$
where K is the kernel function and $\|\cdot\|_H$ is the Hilbert space norm. Is this a valid way forward? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is more or less impossible without knowing more about the $\eta$ function (and even then it might not be easy). So: what do you know about $\eta$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you for the reply, the functions $\eta$ have the following properties: They belong to the Schwarz class $\mathcal{S}$ also $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \eta(y)\,dy=1, \, \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}y^{\alpha}\eta(y)\, dy=0, \,\,\text{for all}\,\, \alpha,\,1\le [\alpha] < N$ also $|\eta(x)| \le c \bigl(1 + |x|\bigr)^{-K/2}$ i.e they decay fast. $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $[\alpha]$ is sum of the indices, $N$ is the order of moment condition.

Comment: @PhoemueX any suggestions?

Comment: The closest thing I know is theorem 2.4 (see also corollary 2.5) in the following paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3649716#metadata_info_tab_contents But for this you need to know that the translates that you consider form a riesz sequence. I guess this holds if $h$ is small.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will check it out.